# How to make iOS Mail.app recognize Courier's namespace prefix?

Tags: macos, email, imap, ios

I am using a Courier IMAP server which, per default, uses the 'INBOX.' prefix for all folders. On Mac OS X as a client this works just fine. On iOS however, I have to manually configure in the advanced settings an IMAP prefix of "INBOX". How can I make this work automatically? Do I have to configure something on the Courier server, or is this a limitation in iOS?